# Plone dexterity model-driven type relationfield

Tags: plone, dexterity

Is it possible to add a relationfield to plones dexterity through the web? I mean by editing the field model xml file.

I know how to add relationfields to the schema model (.py), but how to accomplish the same in the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field is currently lacking from plone.schemaeditor code. There's an issue open: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1671